# Convert JSON from a URL to dataframe (Pyspark and Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a URL such as:

```
the_given_URL = https://blahblah.blahblah.com/raw/AAA/B_B_B/C-C/DD_DD/W/config/smth.json?token=AAArebNfNdB5Ypd9de2NH1ifSCzqA-aEks5dTcabwA%3D%3D
```

which contains a Json formatted data and may update regularly.

I couldn't find a way to convert this to a dataframe. Both Scala and Pyspark ways could be helpful.

I have tried something like

```
  val df = sqlContext.read.json("the_given_URL")
```

but i get the following error:

```
  19/08/05 17:43:13 WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.

  java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https
```

Please consider the error that I get is for **the given URL**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use requests library to access the webpage. This should help you with sta
rting up

```
import json
import requests

req = requests.get("path to json")
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([json.loads(line) for line in req.iter_lines()])
```

Comment: There is no "path to json" there is a URL with the given format above ("the given URL"). I get error when I give that URL. I used the method that you suggest which is the same as one I put here for Scala but the similar error I get.